# How to use the Xmx command? (JVM Heap memory)

Tags: java, oracle, heap-memory, oim

I'm new in the Oracle world and I'm working with Oracle Identity Analytics (OIA). In the test environment everything is ok, but in production environment i'm getting an "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError", so when I checked the Xmx and Xms I saw that I had Xmx:512m and Xms:512m, that's why I'm trying to modify the Xmx value.

I want to modify the Xmx and Xms values so I wrote the following line in my PuTTY:

> $ java -Xmx1024m

But the PuTTY shows me the following:

> Usage: java [-options] class [args...] (to execute a class) or
>          java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...] (to execute a jar file)
>
> where options include:...

Seems like I'm forgetting something after "Xmx1024m", but what? Well, now I know I'm forgetting Jar file, Class or App name but I have no idea how to get any of those things. I tried putting "$AdminServer" after "Xmx1024m" but it didn't work.

My Java version is 1.6.0_45 Oracle JRockit build R28 and the Operative Systems is Linux Server 6.5.

Regards!

Comment: As the message shows, you're missing the class or the jar file to execute.

Comment: Hi Kayaman,

Yes, but what file? And where is this file normally located?

Thank you!

Comment: Well that depends entirely on which Java program you intend to run. Of course that program may have a separate configuration place where you could put java options, but I'm not familiar with the programs you described, so it's up to you to sort it out.

Comment: Ok, anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass filepath to execute. Of course, you can run

```
java -Xmx1024m
```

but Java doesn't know what file should be executed

Comment: Hi Artur!

Great, but what file should I reference?

Thank you!

Comment: File to be executed of course. You probably want to run some .jar file

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the program-name/filename/jar-name,whatever it is,with path for which you want to set/reset the java heap size.

e.g

- ```
  java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar xi.jar
  ```
- ```
  java -Xmx64m ${PROGRAM_NAME}
  ```

Hope this helps you.Or to help you better,could you please tell us what exactly is your scenario?

Comment: Thank you very much! Although, if I would like to use the program name, where could I get it? 


I tried putting the PID using the following:


`Java –Xmx1024 32545`


But it didn’t work..

Comment: I will describe the full scenario inside the post.

Comment: Could you please share the complete exception?From that we can try to figure out why exactly you were getting the exception and which program name we have to pass may be that we can decide.